# Dynamic news paper layout using asp.net C# web form

Tags: css

Dynamic news paper layout using asp.net C# web form. I am trying achieve dynamic news paper but not getting how to set news paper size page layout inside slider. And also when I click particular area of news papers then that area news should be display in new page using Repeater control or any other suitable control to get this requirement.

Below is my all code.

```
   <head runat="server">
<title></title>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="Box">
        <div class="smallbox">
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="Small0.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="Small1.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="Small2.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="Test.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="Test.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="Test.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="Test.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="Test.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="Test.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="Test.jpg" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="bigbox">
            <img id="BigImg" alt="" src="" />
        </div>
        <div id="bomdiv">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl="arrow-left.jpg" OnClientClick="return LeftChange()" />
            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="arrow-right.jpg" OnClientClick="return RightChange()" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I am trying to achieve like any of below url.

http://www.epaperoheraldo.in/

http://tribune.com.pk/epaper/

Note:

Big image size is 900*552.

Small image size is 165*150.

My screen size is 1583px;

Image name rule is: Small0.jpg, Small1.jpg, Small2.jpg ......... Big0.jpg, Big1.jpg, Big2.jpg ......................

The above code got from google but I am trying to achieve same above any of line.

Comment: Your question is neither c# not asp.net. Regarding "how to set ... layout inside slider" - if I copy all code into https://jsbin.com/hofopiyiju/edit?html,output - what is the exact problem there? What is slider?

Comment: I already told that in above question using Repeater, I think you know repeater will come under asp.net and I am trying before that I want to understanding html and j query think, so that why posted these, My question only start with dynamic. Come to the problem already above mention two links I need to achieve like that for that what I have use, please suggest do not be getting confused do not down vote, if you do not want to answer. @2316116 3

Comment: Your question is still unclear. Do you want to display the list of images at left  using the Repeater control?

Comment: Yes both should in repeater control. @2316116

Comment: This question is not related to c# or asp.net . This is a design issues.

Comment: If design issue then please, update your answer and it will not help to me only and help to future blog users. @arif hussain shigri

Answer (score 0):

For to take some ideas, please check this codes and snippet...

```js
window.onload = function () {
        // show default image(Big image and small image) when first open
        //eq(index) can get object through index
        $(".smallbox .subbox").eq(0).trigger("click");
    }
    //set a global variable index
    var index;
    $(function () {
        //click small box can get this index and show the Big image with this index
        $(".smallbox .subbox").click(function () {
            $("#BigImg").attr("src", $(this).find("img").attr("data-big"));
            $(".smallbox .subbox").removeClass("NewSty");
            $(this).addClass("NewSty");
            this.scrollIntoView(false);
        })
    });
    function LeftChange() {
        $(".NewSty").prev().trigger("click");
    }
    function RightChange() {
        $(".NewSty").next().trigger("click");
    }
```

```css
* {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}

    #Box {
        height: 300px;
        width: 600px;
        border: 1px solid red;
    }

    .smallbox {
        width: 100px;
        height:100%;
        border: 1px solid purple;
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: auto;
        float:left;
    }

    .subbox {
        border: 1px solid yellow;
    }
    .subbox img{width:100%; height:100%;}

    #bigbox {
        width: 300px;
        height: 550px;
        border: 1px solid black;
      float:left;
      margin: 10px;
    }

    #bomdiv {
        width: 500px;
        height: 100px;
    }

    #ImageButton2 {
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 150px;
    }

   .NewSty {
     border : 2px solid blue;
        /*box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px blue;*/
    }

.newsArea{
  position:absolute;
  text-decoration:none;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.1);
 }

.newsArea:hover{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,.5);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="Box">
        <div class="smallbox">
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003_Thumb.JPG" data-big="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003.JPG"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003_Thumb.JPG" data-big="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003.JPG"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003_Thumb.JPG" data-big="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003.JPG"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003_Thumb.JPG" data-big="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003.JPG"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003_Thumb.JPG" data-big="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003.JPG"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003_Thumb.JPG" data-big="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003.JPG"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003_Thumb.JPG" data-big="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003.JPG"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003_Thumb.JPG" data-big="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003.JPG"/>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003_Thumb.JPG" data-big="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003.JPG" />
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="subbox">
                <a href="#">
                    <img alt="" src="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003_Thumb.JPG" data-big="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003.JPG"/>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>

         <a id="ImageButton1" style="float:left;margin-top:100px;background-color:yellow;" href="#" onclick="LeftChange()"><</a>
      
        <div id="bigbox">
          <img id="BigImg" alt="" src="" style="width:100%;"/>
        </div>
           
        <a id="ImageButton2" style="float:left;margin-top:100px;background-color:yellow;" href="#" onclick="RightChange()">></a>

    </div>
      
      
      <!-- when Selected paper changed, this areas must refresh for selected page -->
      
      <a class="newsArea" style="left:150px; top:100px; width:140px; height:120px;"
              href="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003.JPG" target="_blank" onclick="alert('new page will open')">&nbsp;</a>
      
      <a class="newsArea" style="left:300px; top:40px; width:70px; height:200px;"
              href="http://epaper.tribune.com.pk/Images/Karachi/20170109/11201701090003.JPG" target="_blank" onclick="alert('new page will open')">&nbsp;</a>
```

Comment: What is difference between my code and your code logic?. @Serhat MERCAN

Comment: Simple differents there not important but I wanted to show that how are tribune website or similars working. You must change the html codes and javascript codes with server side codes (asp.net). The image sources too...

Comment: I check your code is not working properly, please can you try your code using asp.net web form. @Serhat MERCAN

Comment: Where is not working? Every thing working in snippet! What is the problem you that you found?

Comment: Also, my codes are to be sample for your page. I will not wirte all of your page.. You must adaptate code for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Replace repeated pieces of HTML code with a code for Repeater.

Example: the left list includes multiple items and each item is wrapped by

```
<div class="subbox">
   <a href="#"><img alt="" src="{...}.jpg" /></a>
</div>
```

i.e., instead of `<div class="smallbox">...</div>` add Repeater as

```
<div class="smallbox">
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
   <div class="subbox">
       <a href="#"><img alt="" src="<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>" /></a>
   </div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

and the code for data could be

```
List<string> data = new List<string>() { "Small0.jpg", "Small1.jpg", "Small2.jpg" };
Repeater1.DataSource = data;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

That should output same html code with different images

```
<div class="subbox">
    <a href="#"><img alt="" src="Small0.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<div class="subbox">
    <a href="#"><img alt="" src="Small1.jpg" /></a>
</div>
...
```